# How to downgrade a rails app from 3.2 to 2.3.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-2

I've created a rails 3.2 site/app  but the hosting company I wanted to use only supports rails 2.3

Is there any easy option to downgrade. As a long sort , I tried changing my Gemfile on my dev copy but it complains about various dependencies.

Is there any easy way to downgrade  or am I forced to create a new 2.3 app and recreate the files?

Comment: I'd seriously reconsider your choice of hosting company.  If you're going to move, move forwards.

Comment: Which hosting company is this? Just to, you know, name and shame

Comment: eukhost - your all correct I'm looking at moving :)

Comment: I'm working on a 2.3 app having previously developed a 3.1 app.  I'm having to be paid a lot more money to suffer the pain ... so I would strongly agree with the others - whatever the benefits of the host you were considering, choose a different one ...

Comment: why dont you get your own VM and then you can install whatever you like on there and run rails 3.2?